# Prove $\epsilon_n\le c^{f_n}$ where $f_n$ is the Fibonacci sequence by induction

Tags: numerical-methods, secant

Let $f\in C^2(a, b)$ assume that $|f'(x)|\ge \delta > 0$ for all $x \in [a, b], f(p) = 0$ and that the secant method defines a sequence $\{p_n\}$ converging to
$p$.

I showed that $|e_{n+1}| = |\frac{f''(\alpha_1)}{f'(\alpha_2)}e_ne_{n-1}|$ for every $n\ge 1$ and for some $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \in [a, b]$.

I showed that $|e_{n+1}| \le M|e_n||e_{n-1}|$ for some constant $M$.

I also showed that $\epsilon_{n+1}\le\epsilon_n\epsilon_{n-1}$ given $\epsilon_n:=M|e_n|$.

How can I show that if $p_0$ is close enough to $p$, there exists
$0\le c < 1$ such that for every $n\ge 2$, then $\epsilon_n\le c^{f_n}$ where $f_n$ is the Fibonacci sequence by induction?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any sequence solving the recursion
$$
g_{n+1}=g_n+g_{n-1}
$$ 
can be expressed via the Fibonacci-sequence with $f_0=0$, $f_1=1$ (and thus $f_{-1}=1$) as
$$
g_n=g_1f_n+g_0f_{n-1}
$$
Now set $g_0=\ln(ϵ_0)$, $g_1=\ln(ϵ_1)$ and prove by induction that $ϵ_k\le e^{g_k}$. This is true for $k=0,1$ and if true up to $k\le n$, then also
$$
ϵ_{n+1}\le ϵ_{n}ϵ_{n-1}\le e^{g_n+g_{n-1}}=e^{g_{n+1}}
$$
Now use something like $f_{n-1}\le f_n$ for $n>0$ to get to the claim.

Answer (score 0):

I will show that
if
$\epsilon_n
\le c^{f_n}
$
and
$\epsilon_{n-1}
\le c^{f_{n-1}}
$
then
$|\epsilon_{n+k}|
\le c^{f_{n+k}}
$
for $k \ge 1$.

Proof.

$\begin{array}\\
|\epsilon_{n+1}| 
&\le |\epsilon_n||\epsilon_{n-1}|\\
&\le c^{f_n}c^{f_{n-1}}\\
&= c^{f_n+f_{n-1}}\\
&= c^{f_{n+1}}\\
\end{array}
$

Then proceed by induction.

We can choose
$c
=\max(\epsilon_{n-1}^{1/f_{n-1}}, \epsilon_{n}^{1/f_{n}})
$.

Comment: $\epsilon_n \le c^{f_n}$ is what I want to show, not a condition!

Comment: Choose $c$ so that  is true for $n$ and $n-1$. It will then be true for $n+1$.

Comment: I revised my answer.